# How do I set the highlight color of a result set?

Tags: geocortex

I'm working with Geocortex Essentials configuring a viewer based on the Viewer for HTML 5.2.2. My workflow is functioning as designed, confirmed by the correct placement of pushpins. What I really want is the result set from my workflow to be highlighted on the screen (yellow would be great). How do I change the highlight color in the HTML5 viewer? Is this functionality the Silverlight viewer has but HTML5 viewer currently lacks?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are presenting the results, you can set the highlight color two different ways.

If you are using a Select Features activity, you can choose a highlight color in the layer properties for the layer in Essentials Manager.

If you are using a Run External Command activity to add markup, you can use the Update Graphics Layer activity to re-set the renderer that will be used in the markup layer.

Note: for Geocortex product-specific questions, you should also ask on the Latitude Geographics forums for a faster response.